# the meaning of 'I would have tried to do'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, past-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

> "It matters little," she said, softly. "To you, very little. Another idol has displaced me; and if it can cheer and comfort you in time to come, *as I would have tried to do,* I have no just cause to grieve."

(from "A Christmas Carol" by Charles Dickens)

Here, what's the meaning of the expression 'as I would have tried to do'? Is 'would' a substitute for 'will' in the expression of 'I will have tried to do'(future perfect)? In particular, please tell me the exact meanings of 'as' and 'would' respectively.

Comment: "I would have done" is sometimes called [third conditional](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162814/i-would-do-i-would-have-done-what-are-the-grammar-terms-of-this-tense-mood) in ESL classes.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember rightly, this is Scrooge remembering how his love of money had caused a separation from his fiancée. She says that, **if they had married**, she would have done her best to 'cheer and comfort' him in bad times, and she hopes that money will do the same.

Comment: Wow, finally I got it. Many thanks for your very helpful answer.